# How to correct character encoding in IE8 native json?

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, unicode, encoding

I am using json with unicode text, and am having a problem with the IE8 native json implementation.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<script>
    var stringified = JSON.stringify("สวัสดี olé");
    alert(stringified);
</script>
```

Using json2.js or FireFox native json, the `alert()` string is the same as in the original one. IE8 on the other hand returns Unicode values rather than the original text `\u0e2a\u0e27\u0e31\u0e2a\u0e14\u0e35 ol\u00e9` . Is there an easy way to make IE behave like the others, or convert this string to how it should be ? And would you regard this as a bug in IE, I thought native json implementations were supposed to be drop-in identical replacements for json2.js ?

Edit: An repro on jsfiddle using the above code - http://jsfiddle.net/vV4uz/

Comment: This is a clear bug in Internet explorer: JSON should be considered unicode encoded, see [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer my own question - Apparently this is not natively possible in IE8, but it does work correctly in the IE9 Beta.

A [fix](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/c6ad8b5d7f4eda3c/232546ca0d750181?pli=1) is possible though:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<script>
    var stringified = JSON.stringify("สวัสดี olé");
    stringified  = unescape(stringified.replace(/\\u/g, '%u'));
    alert(stringified);
</script>
```

Which will correctly alert() back the original string on all of IE, FF and Chrome.

Comment: Strange. I have had a look on http://www.browserstack.com/ for my site, and all versions of IE 6-10 are impacted

Answer (score 1):

If this is before sending to the server, you can encode it first
encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify("สวัสดี olé"))
and use a utf8 decoder on the server

Comment: Thanks. I don't mind doing the decoding on the server if need be, although it's not ideal as it'd mean the server getting different values depending on which browser was being used. How would I then "utf 8 decode it on the server" though (in C#) , I'm still a bit lost...? 

I already use encodeURIComponent when sending to the server, but that doesn't really change the problem.

Comment: http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/03/31/decodeuricomponent-equivalent-in-c/

I do not see why you would get different data depending on browser, IE and FF both support encodeURIComponent

Comment: The data passed in is different depending on browser (as in the original question), so the output is different too. encodeURIComponent just lets me shift the problem from client to server, but I'm still looking for a way to actually correct the problem with either Javascript on the client or C# on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure, your server is properly configured. Mine was replying, even for unicode JSON files:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think regexp:

> unescape(stringified.replace(/\u/g, '%u'));

is too aggresive. If you had a string '\u' in your input that wasn't the UTF character, it would still catch it.

I think what you need is this:

> unescape(stringified.replace(/([^\\])\\u([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])/g,"$1%u$2"));

This would only change \uxxxx sequences if x is a digit and the whole sequence is not proceeded by a backslash (\).